# MySQL - delete line from TEXT field if it is similar to another line

Tags: mysql

I have some text fields with values like:

```
`FOO` is <1.23
`BAR` is <1.23
```

and I want to remove the 'FOO' line, but only when 'BAR' exists and has the same value (in this case, '<1.23') - any suggestions?

Note that 'FOO' and 'BAR' are constant - i.e. I'm never looking for a 'BING' and 'BONG' with matching values - it's always 'FOO' and 'BAR'.

Final note - there may be other lines in the field, either before, after, or in the middle of the target values.

Just to clarify - those values are not two separate rows - they are multi-line values in a text field on a single row, so an update is required, not a delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following delete statement:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    field LIKE '%`FOO`%' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
            WHERE REPLACE(t2.field, 'BAR', 'FOO') = t1.field);
```